How can I express a definite integral involving arc tangent as a linear combination over $\mathbb{Q}$?
In a public forum there was this problem : find all natural numbers $n$ such that
\begin{equation}
\displaystyle I_n:= \int_0^1 x^n \arctan x dx
\end{equation}
is a rational number.
The answer is: all natural numbers $n$ such that $n=4k+3$.
You can prove it by various methods. For example you can find the recursion formula using integration by parts. Then, Baker’s theorem proves that $I_0, I_1, I_2$ are not rational but $I_3=1/6$ is !
Then someone who solved this problem using an infinite inverse tangent serie proposed the following related problem.
Show that
\begin{equation}
\displaystyle J_n=\int_0^1 t^n \arctan^2(t)dt
\end{equation}
is a linear combination over $\mathbb{Q}$ of $\{\pi, \log 2, 1\}$ if and only if $n \geq 3$ is of the form $4k+3$.
I tried using integration by parts: $u=(\arctan t)^2$; $du=\frac{2 \arctan t}{1+t^2}dt$; $dv=t^ndt$; $v=\frac{t^{n+1}}{n+1}$.
But I have encountered technical difficulties to establish my recursion formula.
Any help/hint would be appreciated.
Many thanks.

Using integration by parts, if your assertion is true, then $\int_0^1 t^n (\tan^{-1}(t))^2dt$ for $n=4k+1$, $k \ge 0$ is linear combination over $\mathbb{Q}$ of ${1,\pi,\pi^2,\log{2}}$. The best I could see using integration by parts is that it links $4k+3$ and $4k+1$ case.

Thank you Sam. In the case, $n=4k+3$, we’re supposed to meet the Catalan’s constant $G$. Perhaps more advanced tools (than integration by parts) are required to treat $J_n$ after all.

In $J_n$ the coefficient of Catalan constant is
$\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n+1} \cos \left(\frac{n\pi }{2}\right)$
